# object name + dot + tab does return list of methods twice in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebook + py3, local running

Could anyone please help me with fixing it?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng6v2.png)

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3238


@takluyver
"The bug is actually coming from IPython. It should be fixed when we release 6.3.

ipython/ipython#10969"